# async-await does not run well on Flutter

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter, async-await, sqflite

**I updated sqlite database in using code,(this method working correctly)**

```
  updateSubmitRequest(int id, String status) async {
    var db = await db1;
    await db.rawUpdate('''
    UPDATE submitRequestTable
    SET status = ?
    WHERE id = ?
      ''', [status, id]);
  }
```

**update.dart**
I updated status like this,

```
 print('before update ${submitRequest[i].status}');
        await HelperDatabase1()
            .updateSubmitRequest(submitRequest[i].id, 'Pending');
 print('after update ${submitRequest[i].status}');
```

**display**

```
List submitRequest = (await HelperDatabase1().displaySubmitRequest());
```

**method**

```
  displaySubmitRequest() async {
    var db = await db1;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps =
        await db.query('submitRequestTable');

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return SubmitRequestModel(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
          equipmentId: maps[i]['equipmentId'],
          woDescriptionId: maps[i]['woDescriptionId'],
          details: maps[i]['details'],
          priorityId: maps[i]['priorityId'],
          workTypeId: maps[i]['workTypeId'],
          sourceId: maps[i]['sourceId'],
          fileName: maps[i]['fileName'],
          filepath: maps[i]['filepath'],
          isOffline: maps[i]['isOffline'],
          systemDate: maps[i]['systemDate'],
          username: maps[i]['username'],
          subItemId: maps[i]['subItemId'],
          status: maps[i]['status']);
    });
  }
```

in my LogCat output like this,

> ```
> I/flutter (15908): before update success
> I/flutter (15908): after update success
> ```

**Why doesn't it change to Pending?**
My update method runs correctly.

Comment: 1. What is `submitRequest` and where it comes from? 2. Are you updating `submitRequest` after you update db?

Comment: are you getting `List submitRequest = (await HelperDatabase1().displaySubmitRequest());` one more time just after you make `updateSubmitRequest`? after DB update you need to get the list again to see the updated details.

Comment: Oopss..I think that's the reason..I will checl and let you know